# Which data structure to choose?

Tags: java, data-structures, guava

Need to choose optimal data structure for fast work with list of locations and regions.

There is simple POJO for locations(cities):

```
public class Location {

    private String name;
    private int post; //id
```

And for regions(districts):

```
public class Region {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<Location> cities;
```

And finally I have `List` of `Region` objects.
What I need to do:

1. Search Locations name by its post(id)
2. Search Locations post by its name. *Note*: Name is not unique, so I need to prefer some concrete Location over another in case of identical names

The question is what data structure should I use? 
I am thinking of TreeMap with contains ALL the Locations from ALL regions. So I can fast get location by Name(string). 
For p 1. I have solution: post of Location contains id of Region. So If Region have id=1, then its Locations post will be 10001, 10002 etc.
Or maybe I need to choose some new Collections type introduced by Guava, since it already present in project?

Comment: You shouldn't link entities by ids, you should link them directly by references, that's what they're for.

Comment: @svick I need to use id's here to work with client, which sends and receives only id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add all locations to two `HashMap`s:

1. one with the all Locations with Location name as the key and a List of Location as value.
2. other with id as the key and the Location as the value?

Preferably hide the two hashmaps in one class doing the lookups for you.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Good point, but remains two question: how to define "prefered" Locations(for case when Name is identical). Maybe add `priority` field into Location. And second: how to prettily synchronize changes of original List with this two map?

Comment: Well is one Location preferred over the other? I suggested a List of Location for each name (List as the values in the Map). So add them to the list in the preferred order if any and choose the first one (then you might not need the List at all). Or you could present them all with additional information such as the Region. Second point is up to object orientation, hide it all behind a class, only update in one place and that place updates the maps as well etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to create class `LocationRepository`:

```
class LocationRepository {
    Location getById(int id);
    Collection<Location> getByName(String id);
}
```

This repository should hold 2 collections: Map (either HashMap or TreeMap of locations: `Map<Integer, Location>` where key is the location ID. The second map should be `[MulitMap][1]` from Guava that maps between name and collection of matching locations.

Comment: what MultiMap implementation to choose?

Comment: @vacuum implementation depends on your application require. You could find many Multimap implementations. HashMultimap is a choice, please note you should overwrite the hashcode and equals methods for key class.